# Variable ViewPoint coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, options

Can I use the option `ViewPoint` on `Graphics3D[]`, with its setting a variable function? For example:

> ```
> ViewPoint -> {Sin(t),Cos(t),t} /. t->Tmax
> ```

where `Tmax` varies with another parameters

Comment: I would think that you could, but could you provide the context in which you want to use this, to make sure? Also, make sure to use `Sin[t]`, `Cos[t]`.

Comment: You might be interested in looking up the implementation of the function `SpinShow[]` from the old package ``Graphics`Animation` ``.

Comment: Sure, but why didn't you just try it? `Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Cuboid[], Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {Sin[t], Cos[t], t}, SphericalRegion -> True],
 {t, 2, 10}
 ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Tetrahedron[],
  ViewPoint -> 
   5 {Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
     Cos[\[Phi]]}],
 {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]}]
```